# problem in uploading sample video file to the server

Tags: iphone

I want to upload sample video file to the server wen i pressed button. I used the code like below.

```
-(IBAction)buttonAction
{
NSMutableURLRequest* post = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://115.111.27.206:8081/vblo/upload.jsp"]];
    [post setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];


    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------358734318367435438734347"];

    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];

    [post addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];


    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"videofile\"; filename=\"videofile.3gp\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video" ofType:@"3gp"] 
                      dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    [post setHTTPBody:body];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:post returningResponse:nil error:nil];

    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    UIAlertView *statusAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:(NSString *)returnString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil];
            [statusAlert show];
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set HTTP header also as follows:

```
NSMutableURLRequest* post = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://115.111.27.206:8081/vblo/upload.jsp"]];
[post setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];


NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------358734318367435438734347"];

NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];

[post addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];


NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"videofile\"; filename=\"videofile.3gp\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


[body appendData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video" ofType:@"3gp"]]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


[post setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:post returningResponse:nil error:nil];

NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(returnString);
```

or if you want asynchronous request then you can call initWithRequest method of NSURLConnection.

Comment: thanks for ur reply. i modified that code as above and i am getting warnings&app terminating.  I am beginner to iphone apps so i felt confuse. pls help me out.

Comment: Hi, I didn't see what you were loading as data before, you were loading the string as data instead of video data, I have corrected it on the above code, now try..

Comment: yeah, now i corrected that, but it's giving as upload video.is that code is enough for uploding sample video. i think from server the mesg should come like uploaded successfully, i am not  getting like that.

Comment: hmm, can you see the uploaded video file on server? are you returning some message from your jsp based on successful upload or failed upload? I uploaded the audio file using above code before, it worked fine, though my server side was php..

Comment: yeh from jsp mesg should be like successful upload, i am not getting like that. and i did'nt see video file which i used on server.

Comment: try putting "video/3gpp" instead of "application/octet-stream" in [body appendData... method. not sure why octet-stream is not working...

Comment: Actually wen i debug the app it was not even comming to buttonAction method. I dont know were i made mistake. Thank u so much Sanniv for reply & for ur patience.